# Descriptive tables - how to create a table containing both numeric and categorical variables

Tags: r

I can't find a really intuitive way of doing the most basic thing; creating a summary table with my base variables. The best method I've found is currently using tapply:

```
seed(200)
my_stats <- function(x){
    if (is.factor(x)){
        a <- table(x, useNA="no")
        b <- round(a*100/sum(a),2)

        # If binary
        if (length(a) == 2){
            ret <- paste(a[1], " (", b[1], " %)", sep="")
        }
        return(ret)
    }else{
        ret <- mean(x, na.rm=T)
        if (ret < 1){
            ret <- round(ret, 2)
        }else{
            ret <- round(ret)
        }
        return(ret)
    }
}

library(rms)
groups <- factor(sample(c("Group A","Group B"), size=51, replace=T))
a <- 3:53 
b <- rnorm(51)
c <- factor(sample(c("male","female"), size=51, replace=T))

res <- rbind(a=tapply(a, groups, my_stats),
      b=tapply(b, groups, my_stats),
      c=tapply(c, groups, my_stats))
latex(latexTranslate(res))
```

The res contains:

```
> res
  Group A     Group B       
a "28"        "28"          
b "-0.08"     "-0.21"       
c "14 (56 %)" "14 (53.85 %)"
```

Now this works but it seems very complex and not the most elegant solution. I've tried to search for how to create descriptive tables but the all focus on the table(), prop.table(), summary() for just single variable or variables of the same kind.

My question: Is there a package/function that allows an easy way of creating a good-looking latex table? If so, please give a hint of how to get the above result.

Thanks!

Comment: Which question is your question? The one in the title about creating a table with summary information about your variables, or the one at the end about making a pretty latex table?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I'm mostly interested in just getting the cells. Formatting LaTeX perhaps not really an R issue

Comment: See the R `Hmisc` package `summaryM` function.

Comment: @FrankHarrell: Thank you, since I wrote this question I've developed my own way of generating Table 1, you can find it in my Gmisc package see [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Gmisc/vignettes/Descriptives.html) for examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rewrite your function so that it always returns a string
(it sometimes returns a string, sometimes a number, sometimes NULL),
you can call `ddply` on the data.frame, without having to specify all the columns.

```
f <- function(u) {
  res <- "?" 
  if(is.factor(u) || is.character(u)) {
    u <- table(u, useNA = "no")
    if (length(u) == 0 || sum(u) == 0) { res <- "NA" }
    else { res <- sprintf( "%0.0f%%", 100 * u[1] / sum(u) ) }
  } else {
    u <- mean(u, na.rm=TRUE)
    if(is.na(u)) { res <- "NA" }
    else { res <- sprintf( ifelse( abs(u) < 1, "%0.2f", "%0.0f" ), u ) }
  }
  return( res )
}
# Same function, for data.frames
g <- function(d) do.call( data.frame, lapply(d, f) )

library(plyr)
ddply(data.frame(a,b,c), .(groups), g)
```

Since you want LaTeX tables, you may also want to try the following, which does not group the data, but adds sparkline histograms for the numeric variables.

```
library(Hmisc)
latex(describe(d), file="")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this suited my needs the best and I also like the answer since I've completely forgot about the beautiful sprintf() function (or rather, I didn't think it existed in R). The sparkline histograms are really nice and perhaps I'll try to add them in some way to my table. I don't know if the journals accept that kind of advanced tables.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is a tad open ended, since there's the distinct possibility that you will disagree with me on what constitutes a "good-looking LaTeX table".

For instance, I would probably prefer to organize this by row, rather than by column:

```
require(plyr)
require(xtable)
dat <- data.frame(a,b,c,groups)
xtable(ddply(dat,.(groups),summarise,a = my_stats(a),
                                     b = my_stats(b),
                                     c = my_stats(c)))


\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rlrrl}
  \hline
 & groups & a & b & c \\ 
  \hline
1 & Group A & 28.00 & 0.14 & 13 (52 \%) \\ 
  2 & Group B & 28.00 & -0.00 & 13 (50 \%) \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

And of course, much of that is customizable if you look at `?xtable` and also `?print.xtable`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `tables` package for another way that may make this simpler.

Comment: Looks really interesting, is there a tutorial out there for the package?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to create a summary table with both catergorical and continuous variables you should look into the package 'tableone'.

Here is an example of what it can do https://rpubs.com/kaz_yos/tableone-vignette. And here is the pdf documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableone/tableone.pdf

I hope this helps.

- Mike

Comment: The tableone package is interesting but since I wrote this question I've written a package that handles this, Gmisc - see the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Gmisc/vignettes/Descriptives.html)

Comment: Ok great thank you for the replies. I am new to stackoverlow and appreciate the feedback.